# org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.ListSelectionDialog input options?

Tags: eclipse, dialog

i try to display a dialog for selection the fields of a source.
i like to use the ListSelectionDialog, but i'm not sure what to use for the input parameter.
all the examples in the web uses the
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()
as input and yeah, all the projects are displayed.
but i have a list of Fields (IField[]) that i want to show for selection.
the constructor of ListSelectionDialog accept the parameter, but the dialog shows nothing... :(
does anybody has an idea?

Comment: What are you using for the content provider and label provider arguments?

Comment: Hi Greg, i use this one:
 public static IType[] chooseFields(Shell shell, IField[] fields) {

  ILabelProvider labelProvider = new JavaElementLabelProvider(JavaElementLabelProvider.SHOW_DEFAULT);
  ListSelectionDialog dialog = new ListSelectionDialog(shell, fields, new BaseWorkbenchContentProvider(), labelProvider, "please select the fields for creating missing text entries");
  dialog.setTitle("field selection");
  dialog.setMessage("please select the fields");
  dialog.setBlockOnOpen(true);
  if (dialog.open() == Window.OK) {
   return dialog.getResult();
  }
  return null;
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think using `BaseWorkbenchContentProvider` is right. Try `ArrayContentProvider`.

So something like:

```
new ListSelectionDialog(shell, fields, new ArrayContentProvider(), labelProvider, msg);
```

Comment: thank you Greg, I didn't know that this contentProvider is the solution :)